# MySQL OUTER JOIN with COUNTS based on dates

Tags: mysql, sql

In MySQL, I want to do an outer join on tables `table1` and `table2`.

I want to get the count of related `table2` grouped by `code` for today and yesterday only, but I also want to be able to see other `code` types with a count of 0. This is what I have so far

```
SELECT h.code, count(h.code) as count, h.timestamp
FROM table1 h LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 o ON h.code= o.code 
GROUP BY h.code 

UNION 

SELECT h.code, count(h.code) as count, h.timestamp
FROM table1 h RIGHT OUTER JOIN table2 o ON h.code= o.code 
GROUP BY h.code
```

So I want to apply something like this

```
WHERE h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1
```

But also include all records in table1 but with a count of 0

I hope this makes sense and hope someone can help!

Comment: First, are you sure you want to use `UNION` and not `UNION ALL` which does not remove duplicates? Also, why not use a single query, that groups by day, for a 2 day interval?

Comment: @njk you're right but you would need one of the queries to be an ANTI-JOIN if you do UNION ALL

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The problem is that there could be existing codes, but none for the last 2 days. So I can't simply query for the last 2 days. But there could also be results beyond the past 2 days, so I cant do a join before and after. How could I apply an anti-join?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, do you have a table with all codes?

```
select codes.code, coalesce(t.cnt) as cnt
from (select distinct code
      from table1
     ) codes left outer join
     (select code, count(*) as cnt
      from table1
      where timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1
      group by code
     ) t
     on codes.code = t.code
```

That query is a bit more complicated than necessary, because it really wants a codes table for the first part of the query.  Here is a perhaps simpler form, if you have only one table:

```
select code,
       sum(case when timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from table1
group by code
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There isnt a codes table, because the idea was to have codes added dynamically. I tried something similar to 'case when' but there can be results before and after the specified date

Answer (score 0):

> So I want to apply something like this
>
> WHERE h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1
>
> But also include all records in table1 but with a count of 0

As written you're duplicating the results where `h.code= o.code`. So its worth while to do `WHERE h.code is null` in the second query. Because of this that means for that query we don't want to apply where conditions on `h` so we just add it the first query.

```
SELECT h.code, count(h.code) as count, h.timestamp
FROM table1 h LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 o ON h.code= o.code 
 WHERE h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1
GROUP BY h.code 

UNION ALL

SELECT h.code, count(h.code) as count, h.timestamp
FROM table1 h RIGHT OUTER JOIN table2 o ON h.code= o.code 
WHERE h.code is null
GROUP BY h.code
```

If for some reason you wanted to apply the date criteria to `h` and `o` but only if there's a record for `o` then the first where clause would be

```
WHERE h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1
      AND
      (o.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1
        or o.code is null)
```

Comment: Its a valid point about code = NULL. There is still the issue with the first part. There can be entries in table1 with a date before CURRENT_DATE - 1 that may not appear in table2...

Comment: Do you want to apply the date criteria to both h and o?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 h.code, 
 count(case h.code is null then 0 else 1 end) as count, 
 h.timestamp
FROM table1 h LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 o ON h.code= o.code 
WHERE h.timestamp >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1
group by h.code
```